# 'EPERM: operation not permitted' error when building Nuxt app

Tags: npm, nuxt.js

Getting one of the following intermittant errors when running `npm run dev`:

`EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\projects\my_project\.nuxt\components'`

`EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\projects\my_project\.nuxt`

I tried `npm cache clear` to no avail. Some people attribute this issue to npm install folders shared on some network, not my case.

Note: this is a random issue. I just tried again after a couple hours and now it works. But when creating this question, it never worked no matter how many times I tried.

Any idea?

Comment: Try running your command with sudo. EPERM error occurs when you don't have user access on the given directory/file.

Comment: In my case there was a password protected document inside the docs folder.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue. I believe is related on VS Code.

I closed VS Code and stopped my console.
I rebuild Nuxt with 'npm run dev' and reopen VS Code.
Now is working.

Comment: My issue was (and likely yours, too), you can't run `generate` while `dev` is running. Stop `dev` first, then run `generate`.

Answer (score 12):

To solve this issue is only

**Stop dev, Close your CMD and Open CMD again and last you can npm run dev again**

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 6):

Same issue. I'm on windows with VS code. Closed terminal and run again with administrator, then it worked. Permission issue.

Answer (score 5):

first, close the vs code and the bash or cmd runner the project
then
just remove the ".nuxt" directory from the root of your project

Answer (score 2):

I am using webstorm, and this problem also happened to me. I closed my terminal, then I closed webstrom and opened my IDE again and `npm run dev`. It solved my problem and maybe it can solves yours.

Comment: Helped me on PHPstorm as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was running Nuxt inside Docker, and it seemed that this issue was caused by my Docker images using up all the allotted space.

After cleaning up Docker images and containers, things started working again when I reinstalled.

Edit:
Never mind, this issue happens when I change branches with git. **Fixing it is simply about restarting Docker.**

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that the file rights were given to root rather than to my user.

I fixed it using the command:

```
chown -R <user>:<group> .nuxt
```

Make sure to replace the <user> and <group>.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, dev script was already running so it prevented build script to access that directory.